# bash script to compare dates within a diven dir (incl. subdirs)

Tags: bash, find

I would like to write a bash script (or just use a command in the CLI) to

1. find all the instances within a given directory and its subdirectories for a given time period
2. copy those files into a given directory that i could pass as an argument

I'm a newbie to bash scripting.  I'm migrating from one plat to another, so any help would be appreciated, even a link.

Comment: sounds like a question http://stackoverflow.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find -newermt "mar 03, 2010 09:00" -not -newermt "mar 11, 2010" -exec cp {} destination \;
```

Comment: thanks a ton.  i should add (for the archives) that it should be 'find . xxx' instead of without, since i wanted it to be recursive.  very very much appreciated!

Comment: @jml: GNU `find` doesn't require an explicit start directory. It defaults to `.` and is recursive by default.